# Sharepoint workflow not triggering when email received into library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I have a SharePoint library with 2 workflows that have been configured to trigger when an item is created or changed within it.

I want these workflows to start automatically when an email is received into the library but it doesn't seem to be happening. The emails arrive in the library but then nothing happens and I have to start the workflows manually. However, the workflows do start automatically if I create an item in SharePoint for the library.

Is there something I need to configure in order to get the workflows happening automatically with these emails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If You have access to SP server try to check if workflow trigger on email is enabled in SharePoint with the PowerShell command below:

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled
```

If it is False, please enable it with the PowerShell command below and then check the results:

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled = $true
$spWebService.Update()
```

[Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6a246070-b107-43bb-8c99-99fda4fccc1d/workflow-not-being-triggered-by-incoming-email?forum=sharepointgeneral)